# Yandex Maps API. Как привязать событие "click" к крестику внутри searchControl?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Не могу подцепить его с помощью jquery селектора.

Comment: Желательно подсказать куда двигаться, без использования кастомных темплейтов. Если другого выхода нет, то такой ответ тоже подойдёт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подпишитесь на событие [`control.SearchControl@clear`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#event-clear).

```js
ymaps.ready(['Map', 'control.SearchControl']).then(function() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map',
    { center: [55.57, 37.62], zoom: 9, controls: ['searchControl'] },
    { searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search' });
  
  map.controls.get('searchControl').events.add('clear', function() {
    alert('clear');
  });
}).catch(console.error);
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Однако, мне пришлось изменить порядок вашего кода. Не знаю почему, но попытка обработать событие close ранее не была успешной...

Answer (score 0):

Вот код который решил мою проблему.

```
mySearchControl.events.add('clear', function () {
    alert('clear');
});
myMap.controls.add(mySearchControl);
```